# Will $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}|a_n|^p$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis

Given that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n^2$ converges,then, will $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}|a_n|^p$$ converge for $p>2$?

I couldn't find a counterexample neither a proof but it looks to me that this is true. For $p=3/2$, I found the counter example $\sum a_n=\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^{2/3}}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is true.

The key idea is that as $\sum |a_n|^2$ converge, we must have $|a_n|<1$ for all $n\geq N_0$ for some $N_0>0$. Then just notice that if $p>2$, we have $|a_n|^p<|a_n|^2$ for all $n\geq N_0$ which implies that $\sum |a_n|^p$ converge as well.